# I can not connect to wireless network Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, wireless, networking, drivers, broadcom

Below is my wireless card information.

Command :

```
sudo lshw -C network
```

Output :

```
 *-network UNCLAIMED     
   description: Network controller
   product: BCM4313 802.11b/g/n Wireless LAN Controller
   vendor: Broadcom Corporation
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
   version: 01
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list
   configuration: latency=0
   resources: memory:f0500000-f0503fff
```

Below is my kernel version.

```
Linux chinthaka-PC 3.5.0-37-generic #58~precise1-Ubuntu SMP Wed Jul 10 17:51:56 UTC 2013 i686 i686 i386 GNU/Linux
```

If I install the Broadcom driver using the additional drivers window I can see the wireless networks and I cannot connect to them.

I have followed many threads in Ubuntu forums to get this work and none of them worked for me as of now, but when I execute the following commands, I can connect to the wireless network, but when I restart my computer the wireless is no longer there. I have to install the broadcom driver from scratch and execute these commands again.

```
sudo modprobe -r wl
sudo apt-get install linux-firmware-nonfree
sudo apt-get remove --purge bcmwl-kernel-source
sudo modprobe b43
```

I have following entries in the  `/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf` file.

```
blacklist bcma
blacklist b43
blacklist b43legacy
blacklist bcma
blacklist ndiswrapper
blacklist brcm80211
```

Please can someone help me to overcome this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Please open the terminal and run:

```
lspci -nn -d 14e4:
```

Is your device 14e4:4727? If so, I believe the correct driver is brcmsmac; one of its dependencies is bcma which you have blacklisted...twice! Please amend your blacklist file to remove those two entries. Next, do:

```
sudo su
echo brcmsmac >> /etc/modules
modprobe brcmsmac
exit
```

Now is your wireless working? It may take a reboot.

Comment: It is working fine now. Thank you very much chili555.